# How does one simplify $\frac{32}{n^2}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right) - 20$ to $-4 + \frac{32}{2n}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How does one simplify $\frac{32}{n^2}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right) - 20$ to $-4 + \frac{32}{2n}$?

[$\frac{32}{n^2}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right) - 20\, \text{to}\, -4 + \frac{32}{2n}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqGX5.png)

I was in the middle of finding the definite integral
$$\int_{0}^{4} (2x -5)~dx$$
when I found myself having a hard time factoring between the stated equations.

I see how the minuend will factor to $\frac{32}{2n}$; but I don't know how we go from $-20\, \text{to}\, -4$. Does this have to do with the factor of the subtrahend summation or with how we simplify the quotient at large?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 \frac{32}{n^2}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)-20 = \frac{32(n^2+n)}{2n^2}-20 = \frac{32n^2}{2n^2}+\frac{32n}{2n^2}-20 = 16+\frac{16}{n}-20 = -4+\frac{16}{n}.
$$

In the future, try to format math expressions in the title and question using mathjax, see here for a tutorial: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) .

Comment: Thank you Tim. I understand now : we split up the sum in the minuend to get a number plus a quotient with the variable. The number will be added to the subtrahend to give us -4 when we take the limit to find the definite integral. Thank you so much. I'll add this to my tool box. I hope the post was appropriate. I didn't realize that since we can cancel simplify that addend on the minuend's side, the number there is independent of the right hand addend, 32 on 2n.